# Leaflet Js Page Scrolling Issue on IOS

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am currently using leaflet 1.6.0 stable version. 
Everything works fine except the page is preventing scroll on IOS phones(tested on safari & chrome).
I have done some workarounds via this [thread](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5425.). Already set `dragging` & `tap` as false and still not working. Have tried other events also like `scrollwheel`.

Does anyone find the solution yet !

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution yet? Thanks

Comment: Not yet, but I figured a way to work it , not a truly correct one tho. Here is how I did it atm. ` <h2>my title</h2> <div id="map"></div> ` I gave some space between page title and map div. That works for me altho its weird.